# Application not finding Oracle Thin driver running on Windows 10

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to register Oracle Thin driver in my application, but keep getting a ClassNotFound Exception.  I am running jdk11 on Windows 10.

Here is my code

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        Class.forName("jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521/XE");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME,
                PASSWORD);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Error connecting to the database", ex);
   }
```

I have also tried "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" but it still can't find it.  I have a connection in the database services using the string in the code, so I don't understand why my application cannot find it.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated,

Tom Magaro

Comment: Did you download the [Oracle JDBC Driver](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html)?

Comment: `"jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521/XE"` is the URL and not the name of a class - it cannot be used in `Class.forName()` - if the friver class is not found, then it is not found in the CLASSPATH (in this case the JAR file containing the driver is not on the CLASSPATH)

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it, that's why I am able to connect under the Services tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the double slashes, should have been an @. And the slash before the SID should be a colon.

jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
!!             !!

Thanks for your responses.